# Is it possible to link Linkedin with Zoho CRM?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, crm, zoho

Is it possible to link Linkedin with Zoho CRM ? I spoke to Zoho and they said Linkedin don't provide them with an API anymore but they may do it on an individual basis.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Zoho CRM has their own API that you can access.

LinkedIn has a jssdk (api) https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk

So, you could create an application that lives between the two API's and translates information back and forth between the applications. You could check github for an existing projects that may help: https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=zoho+&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

It definitely is not plug and play though, you have to develop some middleware.